# TensorRT create exception when engine is created from sub-process

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

Ran into an issue to run tensorrt from a subprocess. I am not sure whether it is a tensorrt bug or I am doing something wrong. If this is an integration bug, I wonder whether this has already addressed in the new release of tensorflow 1.7.
Here is the summary of error and how to reproduce it.

**Working** TensorRT example Python code with a single process :

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import argparse
import numpy as np
import time
import tensorrt as trt
from tensorrt.parsers import uffparser

uff_model = open('resnet_v2_50_dc.uff', 'rb').read()

parser = uffparser.create_uff_parser()
parser.register_input("input", (3, 224, 224), 0)
parser.register_output("resnet_v2_50/predictions/Reshape_1")


trt_logger = trt.infer.ConsoleLogger(trt.infer.LogSeverity.INFO)

engine = trt.utils.uff_to_trt_engine(logger=trt_logger,
                                 stream=uff_model,
                                 parser=parser,
                                 max_batch_size=4,
                                 max_workspace_size= 1 << 30,
                                 datatype=trt.infer.DataType.FLOAT)
```

**Non-working** TensorRT  example Python code  where
`trt.utils.uff_to_trt_engine()` is called from sub-process :

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import argparse
import numpy as np
import time
import tensorrt as trt
from tensorrt.parsers import uffparser
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import sharedctypes, Queue

def inference_process():
  uff_model = open('resnet_v2_50_dc.uff', 'rb').read()

  parser = uffparser.create_uff_parser()
  parser.register_input("input", (3, 224, 224), 0)
  parser.register_output("resnet_v2_50/predictions/Reshape_1")

  trt_logger = trt.infer.ConsoleLogger(trt.infer.LogSeverity.INFO)
  engine = trt.utils.uff_to_trt_engine(logger=trt_logger,
                                     stream=uff_model,
                                     parser=parser,
                                     max_batch_size=4,
                                     max_workspace_size= 1 << 30,
                                     datatype=trt.infer.DataType.FLOAT)

inference_p = multiprocessing.Process(target=inference_process, args=( ))
inference_p.start()
```

**Console Error Message :**

```
[TensorRT] ERROR: cudnnLayerUtils.cpp (288) - Cuda Error in smVersion: 3
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nvinfer1::CudaError'
what():  std::exception
```

Answer (score 0):

you should import tensorRT in subprocess!

may be:

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import argparse
import numpy as np
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import sharedctypes, Queue

def inference_process():
  import tensorrt as trt
  from tensorrt.parsers import uffparser

  uff_model = open('resnet_v2_50_dc.uff', 'rb').read()

  parser = uffparser.create_uff_parser()
  parser.register_input("input", (3, 224, 224), 0)
  parser.register_output("resnet_v2_50/predictions/Reshape_1")

  trt_logger = trt.infer.ConsoleLogger(trt.infer.LogSeverity.INFO)
  engine = trt.utils.uff_to_trt_engine(logger=trt_logger,
                                     stream=uff_model,
                                     parser=parser,
                                     max_batch_size=4,
                                     max_workspace_size= 1 << 30,
                                     datatype=trt.infer.DataType.FLOAT)

inference_p = multiprocessing.Process(target=inference_process, args=( ))
inference_p.start()
```